# Provide service in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, lazy-loading

A project is importing module A singleton statically (with forRoot) in the app/root module which contains a service which is using a provided service injection token.

```
const providedChildServices: ChildService[] = this._injector.get(ProvidedByChildService, []); //inside the root service
```

This ProvidedByChildService is provided by a module B which is lazy loaded when navigating inside the app.

This behaviour occurs: users is navigating inside app, goes inside route for B module --> everything of module B is lazy loaded --> RootService requests provided 'ProvidedByChildService' but can't find it. Is this architecture possible? It works when I register ProvidedByChildService as a provider in the A module (instead of B).

Comment: I think that service should be in a shared module if 2 or more modules depend on it.

Comment: It would be easier to refactor shared code into a common module that is not lazy loaded. Otherwise you cannot guarantee its availability.

Comment: basic things on services are ... after angular 8 and 9, when you create service by default it is `providedIn : 'root'`, and root service has only one instance for both lazy loaded and eagerly loaded module. If you want separate instance for lazy loaded module, you can use `providedIn: 'any'`, in this case all lazy loaded module and eagerly loaded module have their own instance of services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. It isn't the right architectural choice that a root service depends on a child service.

If a root service depends on a subsequent service, that needs to be in the root as well.

You did not specify reason in why you need to do it. But in the scenario you provided, you do not save bytes of the root bundle, because the child service is already referenced there in the root service, therefore will be bundled with it.

As of why your code does not work - the `_injector` in the root service is the root injector and therefore it does not try to resolve the module by looking into child modules. In angular, loaded modules create a provider tree in which child injectors traverse the tree to the root until they find the provider they look for - not the other way around.

I provide some possible solutions:

1. You move the currently child service into the root.
2. You move the parts of the root service, that are dependent on the child service into a new child service which will be provided in the child module.
3. You mark the child service as a `@Optional` dependency of the root module and add a provider of the root services into the child module `providers` array.

Comment: Option 1 and option 2 looks more approachable than option 3. Option3 gives confusion in future when we want to refactor code.

Comment: Option 1 is the one we currently have. (it's optional for any other module defined in the root module to provide a service to be handled in module A (which is also in the root module), also fine if none are provided). 

The reason why I'm now investigating the scenario I asked, is because there now is a use case to have the service provided by a child module B, and a different service provided by child module C (configuring in flow level instead of root level).

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules

Comment: @Vincent Then I'd provide the 'root' service in module B and module C at the same level (or lower) as the other services. It would be a different instance for each of these modules.